# Anaconda Jupyter Notebook kernel not connecting

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I updated my anaconda recently, from that day on wards I am not able to execute python in jupyter notebook. And I updated Jupyter notebook to 5.7.6. After that, It is not even showing directory while launching, Just blank chrome page(localhost:8888/tree).

Is there any problem in the newer versions?. Should I downgrade?

If I try to start from cmd:

**ERROR**

> In file included from D:\anaconda3\include/Python.h:77:0,
>                    from D:\anaconda3\lib\site-
>
> packages\zmq\backend\cffi__pycache___cffi_ext.c:2:
>
> D:\anaconda3\include/pytime.h:123:59: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list
>
> PyAPI_FUNC(int) _PyTime_FromTimeval(_PyTime_t *tp, struct timeval *tv);
>                                                              ^
>   D:\anaconda3\include/pytime.h:123:59: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
>
> D:\anaconda3\include/pytime.h:131:5: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list
>
> _PyTime_round_t round);
>        ^
>   D:\anaconda3\include/pytime.h:136:5: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list
>
> _PyTime_round_t round);
>        ^
>   D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi__pycache___cffi_ext.c:213:20: fatal error: sys/un.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
>       from notebook.notebookapp import main
>
> File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 47, in \
>
> from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
>
> File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq__init__.py", line 47, in
>
> from zmq import backend
>
> File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py", line 40, in
>
> reraise(*exc_info)
>
> File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
>
> raise value
>
> File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend__init__.py", line 27, in
>
> _ns = select_backend(first)
>
> File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 27, in select_backend
>
> mod = **import**(name, fromlist=public_api)
>
> File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython__init__.py", line 6, in
>
> from . import (constants, error, message, context,
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: windows/linux ?

Comment: windows 10.......

Comment: If you starting Jupyter from command line, make sure that the address that appears in browser is the same as the one that appears in command line. It is not necessarily :8888

Comment: this address appears in browser when i click launch in anaconda navigator

Comment: type `cmd` in search. Type enter (open command line). Type: `jupyter notebook`. When it opens, copy paste the address from `cmd` to browser.

Comment: i tried from cmd. iam getting above error. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190451/discussion-between-vlad-and-bubesh-p).